# PHP include with a variable in the path

Tags: php, variables, path, include

So we build websites that have to ported from local development servers, to a test server, then to a live server. For this reason we have created a variable:

```
<?php $path = '/_Folder_/_SubFolder_'; ?>
```

When we move the website from server to the next, the idea is to simply change the $path definition to retrofit to the new development server. Currently, on each page when we call an include we write:

```
<?php include('../_includes/_css.php'); ?>
```

**but what I'm trying to do is to:**

```
<?php include($path.'/_includes/_css.php'); ?>
```

**my result I hope for is:**

```
<?php include('/_Folder_/_SubFolder_/_includes/_css.php'); ?>
```

**I've been failing miserably resulting in:**

> Warning: include(/*Folder*/_SubFolder_/_includes/_css.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\FREEDOM2012_FREEDOM2012_DEFAULT_\accommodations\guest-rooms.php on line 15

**Other Issue** I still need to include the variable source by calling "../"

```
<?php include('../_includes/_var.php'); ?>
```

if anybody has any insight into how I could do this more efficiently I would be most appreciative. Thank you very much for your time, patience and effort in responding.

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing the string you're feeding to `include()`?

Comment: As you are on a windows server you will need backslashes instead of slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you initailize your $path variable dynamically once forever and environnement-independant ?

like:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Starting with PHP 5.3, you have also the `__DIR__` shortcut that does the same as above.

@see : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Used with `set_include_path` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php you can bootstrap it nicely. and have decent relative paths in your includes.

Answer (score 2):

You need show the previous directory with:

```
<?php include('../_includes/_css.php'); ?>
```

Because you have `../`, if your full path is `css.php = /_Folder_/_SubFolder_/_includes/_css.php`, then you need use this:

```
<?php $path = './_Folder_/_SubFolder_';
include($path.'/_includes/_css.php'); ?>
```

Otherwise, first show full path to file `_css.php`.