# PHP include statement containing echoed PHP variable

Tags: php

I have the required ID variable from this, (there are 1-6 possible values):

```
$new_product['ID'] =$row[2];
```

What I need is to echo a separate 'php-include' depending on this variable, so something like:

```
<?php include 'includes/size/prod/echo $row[2].php'; ?>
```

which would display, includes/size/prod/1.php, includes/size/prod/2.php etc

I don't understand how to phrase the 'echo' within the php.

Comment: <?php include 'includes/size/prod/' . $row[2] . '.php'; ?>

Comment: try include 'includes/size/prod/'.$row[2].php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP include with a variable in the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076974/php-include-with-a-variable-in-the-path)

Comment: Thanks Naruto worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways:

```
//Concatenate array value in double quotes:
<?php include "includes/size/prod/{$row[2]}.php"; ?>

//Concatenate array value outside of quotes:
<?php include "includes/size/prod/".$row[2].".php"; ?>
//or, using single quotes:
<?php include 'includes/size/prod/'.$row[2].'.php'; ?>

//Concatenate variable (not array value) in double quotes:
<?php $page = $row[2]; include "includes/size/prod/$page.php"; ?>
```

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php
- [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)
- [PHP include with a variable in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076974/php-include-with-a-variable-in-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

It's very dangerous to include your **PHP** files with this technic !!
You must prevent this by doing at least a control of included files are PHP

Now to respond to your question:

```
<?php 
// ? $row2 contains more than 1 php file to include ?
//   they are seperated by comma ?

$phpToInclude = NULL;
define(TEMPLATE_INCLUDE, 'includes/size/prod/');

if (isset($row[2])) {
    $phpToInclude = explode($row[2], ',');
}

if (!is_null($phpToInclude)) {
    foreach($phpToInclude as $f) {
        $include = sprintf(TEMPLATE_INCLUDE . '%s', $f);
        if (is_file($include)) {
            // add validator here !!
            include ($include);
        }
        else {
            // file not exist, log your error
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

dear use following working code

```
$row[2]         =   '';
$file_name      =   !empty($row[2])?$row[2]:'default';
$include_file   =  "includes/size/prod/".$file_name.".php";
include($include_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Things get evaluated in double quotes but not in single:

```
$var = "rajveer gangwar";
echo '$var is musician'; // $s is musician.
echo "$var is musician."; //rajveer gangwar is musician.
```

So better to use **double quotes**

Example:

```
// Get your dynamic file name in a single variable.
$file_name      =   !empty($row[0]) ? $row[0] : "default_file";
$include_file   =  "includes/size/prod/$file_name.php";
include($include_file);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the dots for separating a string:
So for instance:

```
$path = 'includes/size/prod/'.$row[2].'.php'; 

include '$path';
```

Or you can put it in a variable:

```
$path = $row[2];
include 'includes/size/prod/$path.php';
```

Php is able to evaluate a variable within a string.